# Python - Group Dates by Month

Tags: python, datetime, python-itertools

Here's a quick problem that I, at first, dismissed as easy. An hour in, and I'm not so sure!
So, I have a list of Python `datetime` objects, and I want to graph them. The x-values are the year and month, and the y-values would be the amount of date objects in this list that happened in this month.
Perhaps an example will demonstrate this better (dd/mm/yyyy):

```
[28/02/2018, 01/03/2018, 16/03/2018, 17/05/2018] 
-> ([02/2018, 03/2018, 04/2018, 05/2018], [1, 2, 0, 1])
```

My first attempt tried to simply group by date and year, along the lines of:

```
import itertools
group = itertools.groupby(dates, lambda date: date.strftime("%b/%Y"))
graph = zip(*[(k, len(list(v)) for k, v in group]) # format the data for graphing
```

As you've probably noticed though, this will group only by dates that are already present in the list. In my example above, the fact that none of the dates occurred in April would have been overlooked.

Next, I tried finding the starting and ending dates, and looping over the months between them:

```
import datetime
data = [[], [],]
for year in range(min_date.year, max_date.year):
    for month in range(min_date.month, max_date.month):
        k = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=1).strftime("%b/%Y")
        v = sum([1 for date in dates if date.strftime("%b/%Y") == k])
        data[0].append(k)
        data[1].append(v)
```

Of course, this only works if `min_date.month` is smaller than `max_date.month` which is not necessarily the case if they span multiple years. Also, its pretty ugly.

Is there an elegant way of doing this?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: To be clear, the dates are `datetime` objects, not strings. They look like strings here for the sake of being readable.

Comment: take a look at counter https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

dates = ['28/02/2018', '01/03/2018', '16/03/2018', '17/05/2018'] 

s = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(dates), format='%d/%m/%Y')
s.index = s.dt.to_period('m')
s = s.groupby(level=0).size()

s = s.reindex(pd.period_range(s.index.min(), s.index.max(), freq='m'), fill_value=0)
print (s)
2018-02    1
2018-03    2
2018-04    0
2018-05    1
Freq: M, dtype: int64

s.plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]

**Explanation:**

1. First create [`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series) from list of `date`s and convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)s.
2. Create `PeriodIndex` by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html)
3. [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) by index (`level=0`) and get counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html)
4. Add missing periods by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by [`PeriodIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.PeriodIndex.html) created by max and min values of index
5. Last plot, e.g. for bars - [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think for just this problem, importing a massive library like pandas is a bit overkill. The counter idea seems more appropriate. In any case, thanks.

Comment: @EriktheRed - No problem, but if need use similar data analyses in future, pandas is better :)

Comment: @EriktheRed - But i understand you, I start to use pandas only because pure python cannot works with large csv files :). And really this library is nice, simplify solutions a lot. Happy coding!

Comment: Looks like I'm going for Pandas. The Counter is not so great after all...

Answer (score 0):

using **Counter**

```
dates = list()
import random
import collections

for y in range(2015,2019):
  for m in range(1,13):
    for i in range(random.randint(1,4)):
      dates.append("{}/{}".format(m,y))

print(dates)
counter = collections.Counter(dates)
print(counter)
```

for your problem with dates with no occurrences you can use the `subtract` method of Counter
generate a list with all range of dates, each date will appear on the list only once, and then you can use subtract 
like so

```
tmp_date_list = ["{}/{}".format(m,y) for y in range(2015,2019) for m in range(1,13)]
counter.subtract(tmp_date_list)
```

Comment: Any way I could keep my dates as native `datetime` objects here, instead of converting them to strings and back again?

Comment: Also, this does not include months with no occurrences in the list. This has the same problem as my `groupby` attempt.

Comment: @EriktheRed, yes you can use native `datetime` objects but you need to create them only with year and month, the Counter will know how to compare them